# I cannot make a running list with the following JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

With following code, I can append a list that is reading data from the form. But I suppose to make running list, so that if I change any input, on click, another list is created with updated information. My appended information is just a single list instead. How can a make a list of appended profile with every update. Please help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
          BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Employee Profile</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Full Name *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="headline">Headline *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="headline" placeholder="Headline" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="position">Current Position</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" placeholder="Current Position">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="spRegion">State/Province/Region * 
                </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="spRegion" required>
            <option>Please select</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia
            </option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="country">Country * </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="country" required>
            <option>Please select</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda
            </option>
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of
            </option>
            <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba
            </option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina
            </option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory
            </option>
            <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam
            </option>
            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands
            </option>
            <option value="CF">Central African Republic
            </option>
            <option value="TD">Chad</option>
            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
            <option value="CN">China</option>
            <option value="CX">Christmas Island
            </option>
            <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands
            </option>
            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
            <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
            <option value="CG">Congo</option>
            <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the
            </option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
            <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
            <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic
            </option>
            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic
            </option>
            <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea
            </option>
            <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
            <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)
            </option>
            <option value="FO">Faroe Islands
            </option>
            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="GF">French Guiana
            </option>
            <option value="PF">French Polynesia
            </option>
            <option value="TF">French Southern Territories
            </option>
            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
            <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GW">Guinea- Bissau
            </option>
            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands
            </option>
            <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)
            </option>
            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IN">India</option>
            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
            <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
            <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
            <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
            <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
            <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic
            </option>
            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
            <option value="LY">Libya</option>
            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MO">Macao</option>
            <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands
            </option>
            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of
            </option>
            <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="NC">New Caledonia
            </option>
            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="NE">Niger</option>
            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="NU">Niue</option>
            <option value="NF">Norfolk Island
            </option>
            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands
            </option>
            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
            <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied
            </option>
            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea
            </option>
            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
            <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
            <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
            <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
            <option value="RU">Russian Federation
            </option>
            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy
            </option>
            <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
            </option>
            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis
            </option>
            <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)
            </option>
            <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon
            </option>
            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
            </option>
            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
            <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe
            </option>
            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia
            </option>
            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
            <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SL">Sierra Leone
            </option>
            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
            <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)
            </option>
            <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands
            </option>
            <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
            <option value="ZA">South Africa
            </option>
            <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
            </option>
            <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
            <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
            <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen
            </option>
            <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic
            </option>
            <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China
            </option>
            <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
            <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago
            </option>
            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands
            </option>
            <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates
            </option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom
            </option>
            <option value="US">United States
            </option>
            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands
            </option>
            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of
            </option>
            <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
            <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British
            </option>
            <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.
            </option>
            <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna
            </option>
            <option value="EH">Western Sahara
            </option>
            <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="education">Education</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="education" placeholder="Education">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="skills">Skills</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skills" placeholder="Skills">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="linkedIn">My LinkedIn URL</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="linkedIn" placeholder="Your Link to Linked In">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create a Job 
              Profile</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn- 
                danger">Cancel</button> -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
      <div id="output">
        <!-- form input goes here -->
      </div>
      <!--  <button type="button" class="btn btn- 
              danger">Cancel</button> -->
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://sabioapi2.azurewebsites.net/scripts/sabio.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    sabio.page.startUp = function() {

      $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', sabio.page.handlers.writeHtml);


      $('button.btn-danger').on('click', sabio.page.hideCar);
    };
    sabio.page.handlers.writeHtml = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // $('#output').show();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var headline = $('#headline').val();
      var position = $('#position').val();
      var spRegion = $('#spRegion').val();
      var country = $('#country').val();
      var education = $('#education').val();
      var skills = $('#skills').val();
      var linkedIn = $('#linkedIn').val();

      $('#output').html(
        '<ul style="list-style: none;">' +
        '<li>' + name + '</li>' +
        '<li> Headline:' + headline + '</li>' +
        '<li> Current Position:' + position + '</li>' +
        '<li> Location' + spRegion + '</li>' +
        '<li> Country' + country + '</li>' +
        '<li> Education:' + education + '</li>' +
        '<li> Skills:' + skills + '</li>' +
        '<li>' + linkedIn + '<a href="https://www.something.com">LinkedIn Profile</a>' + '</li>' +
        '</ul>');
      // $('#output').append('<div><span>make:' +name+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Headline: ' +headline+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Current Position: ' +position+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Location: ' +spRegion+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Country: ' +country+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Education: ' +edcation+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>Skills: ' +skills+
      //                '</span></div><div><span>LinkedIn: ' +linkedIn+'<a href="https://www.something.com">LinkedIn Profile</a>'
      //                );
      $('form')[0].reset();
    };
    sabio.page.hideCar = function() {
      $('#output').hide();
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

from your question, i think this is what you want. Close up your output div (remove the comments) `<div id="output"></div>`
and use an if else for your js code

```
if (!$('#output').html().length) {
  $('#output').html(
    '<ul style="list-style: none;">' +
    '<li>' + name + '</li>' +
    '<li> Headline:' + headline + '</li>' +
    '<li> Current Position:' + position + '</li>' +
    '<li> Location' + spRegion + '</li>' +
    '<li> Country' + country + '</li>' +
    '<li> Education:' + education + '</li>' +
    '<li> Skills:' + skills + '</li>' +
    '<li>' + linkedIn + '<a href="https://www.something.com">LinkedIn Profile</a>' + '</li>' +
    '</ul>');

}else{
  $('#output').append('<div><span>make:' +name+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Headline: ' +headline+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Current Position: ' +position+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Location: ' +spRegion+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Country: ' +country+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Education: ' +education+
                 '</span></div><div><span>Skills: ' +skills+
                 '</span></div><div><span>LinkedIn: ' +linkedIn+'<a href="https://www.something.com">LinkedIn Profile</a>'
                 );}
```